# Angular template directive binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I wrote single file with directive templates. This file is appended to document using `ng-include` directive. Sometimes browser load templates before directive template binding, but not always.

https://plnkr.co/edit/SNhVU6BoM0nbOelJpepE?p=preview

Is there some solution to wait after `ng-include` directive apply html content to document and after that bind directive templates? Maybe should i use different solution to load these templates to html document.

Comment: May I know why are you doing so complex. If you want to use ng-include then write seperate controller for that or write a directive rather that ng-include

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular has 2 builtin possibilities:

1. Yout template should be in file directly included in your 'index.html'. (Sync templates)

> ```
> <script src="templates.js"></script>
> in which:
> app.run(function($templateCache) {
>   $templateCache.put('templateId', '<div></div>')
> })
> ```

2. Each template should be in separate file `template1.html`, `templat2.html`... 
   (Async templates)

P.S. During development templates are always in separate html files, for production usage templates are gathered to js files using build tools.